# Latest Ruby Version not being recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just installed ruby 2.4.1 on my Mac (running sierra) using rbenv. I also installed ruby 2.4.0. Ruby Directories are present.

however, ruby -v gives

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

even after setting "rbenv global 2.4.1" ...

Output from "gem env"

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/marauf/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Output from "rbenv versions"

```
  system
  2.4.0
* 2.4.1 (set by /Users/me/.rbenv/version)
```

ruby-build updated, based on a few other posts.

I can't install latest Rails because it sees ruby 2.0.0 instead of ruby 2.4.1. Assistance Please!!

Answer (score 1):

`rbenv global` doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. `global` only sets the ruby version *where not otherwise specified.* So what other ways can the ruby version be set?

1) `rbenv shell` sets the version in use for the current shell session;

2) `rbenv local` sets the version for use in the current directory. You should see a `.ruby_version` file in your working directory dictating what version of ruby to use and overriding your `rbenv global` command.

You would know immediately if you were doing 1), so I'm betting that you set a ruby version in your project directory at some point, maybe without realizing it. You should be able to create and change to a new directory where your global version is respected.

Note: You may consider this a bit of editorializing, but if you're not totally wedded to rbenv, consider using rvm. rvm has a `use` command that sets the version of ruby in use on the fly, which is terribly convenient.

Comment: Contradictory opinion: I strongly prefer `rbenv` over `rvm`. In the modern era of `Gemfile`s and `bundler`, I don't see any real benefit of `rvm`.

Answer (score 1):

Run these to update the .bashrc or .zshrc file so the new version is by default in your environment:

```
# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda updated ... I *totally* forgot to update my .bashrc_profile with $PATH ... did that and worked well.

thankx for the comments.

Comment: and how did you do that. That would have been a helpful answer.